# find value for key in dictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary,and in which there is value "ProDiscount".
I want to check whether there is any discount or not,
And if there is 0 discount,i want to hide label.But only one who don't have discount.Else to be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple answer like

```
// by default enable your label like
yourlabel.hidden  =NO;

if ([yourdict[@"ProDiscount"] isEqualToString:@"0"])
{
// ProDiscount is equal to zero hidden your label
yourlabel.hidden  =YES;
}
```

Comment: if ([[dictData objectForKey:@"ProDiscount"]isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
      productCell.minDiscount.hidden=YES;
   }
i already did this,but the problem is it hides other promodiscount label also,which have some discount,on load.

Comment: @akankshasingh -- Sister : can you show your code it is easy to solve , else try this once in this place **dictData objectForKey** use **dictData valueForKey**

Comment: reponse :{AdditionDiscount = 0; BrandId = 4233; CatId = 48; FDisId = 6; FinalPrice = 600; ProDisPrice = 0;ProDisType = percentage;ProDiscount = 60; ProId = 56712; ProName = "Trendy Bandey W-279LTBL Blue Men Jeans"; SKUNO = C48P101012R2543;SellingPrice = 600;TotalValues = "0.00"; image = "W-279LTBL_1_12x_885.JPG"; proQnty = 33; prodtmappid = 101012; productMRP = 1499; "size_Val" = 30;  }and there are more than 200 product,and i just want to show discount.
I m able to show it,but if there is 0 discount in any product i just want to hide label,and the data is shown in collection view.

Comment: where you compared ,can you show your comparsion code

Comment: NSString * ProDiscount =dictData[@"ProDiscount"];
    if ([ProDiscount isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        productCell.minDiscount.hidden=YES; }else{productCell.minDiscount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[dictData valueForKey:@"ProDiscount"],@"%"];productCell.minDiscount.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:250.0/255.0 green:39.0/255.0 blue:39.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];productCell.minDiscount.layer.cornerRadius = 2;productCell.minDiscount.clipsToBounds = YES;}

Comment: Seems like you are using cells in tableview and don't know how to handle those.. you sould learn how the cells are reused in a tableview..

Comment: Forcefully create new cell each time and check

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava sir its is dynamic cell in table view

Comment: @akankshasingh -- I think this problem occur in cellforRowAtIndexpath, may be you compare on wrong place,

Comment: nope.m showing it on collectionview cellForItemAtIndexPath

Comment: the problem occurs when i scroll table view

Comment: ya absolutely correct, bz you checked the condition is some wrong place , can you show your code , it is easy to solve else we cant help u

Comment: how ll i show u code?code doesnt fit in comment box.

Comment: ha ha ha , update your question simple , else send your project to my mail id karthik.saral@gmail.com

Comment: i just have to do hidden =no in else part....:P
now its done.....thanks all....:)

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Anbu.Karthik is correct, but the only thing I would change is to implement this in your collectionViewCell:

```
    - (void) prepareForReuse {
           yourlabel.hidden = NO;
      }
```

this way, you will ensure that every time a cell comes up, your label will not be hidden. Since cells are reused, we want to the default behaviors there.